# PDF view in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, pdf-viewer

I am working on an Blackberry application in which I have to show some PDF files in my application.

I know we can show the PDF file as a GOOGLE document, I have already done that. But this time my task is to show PDF files inside application.

Do we have any option to show PDF files in our own application by using some SDK's ?

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont think any blackberry sdk support this facility.
There is only one option to view pdf files offline is to download and view using a third party pdf viewer.

Even blackberry dont have given a built in pdf reader to user,when I was looking for the same issue I found that only one company **SLG Mobile** has made this app(beamreader) and blackberry gave them very special award(dont remember award name now),
so this third party app is free for one month and after that you have to pay nearly 500 Rs as licence fee.

Now for BB10 Adob has created a reader and it comes with device itself.